# Maven Could not resolve dependencies for project MyProject oh

Tags: java, maven

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>deephitomi</artifactId>
    <groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
<artifactId>deephitomi-client</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
        <artifactId>deephitomi-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

deephitomi-common POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>deephitomi</artifactId>
    <groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
<artifactId>deephitomi-common</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.3.10.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>2.5.3</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 使用SpringMVC需配置 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 关系型数据库整合时需配置 如hibernate jpa等 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mysql连接 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 上传文件 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.13.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ERROR:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project deephitomi-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project studio.deepsea:deephitomi-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at studio.deepsea:deephitomi-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for studio.deepsea:deephitomi-common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact studio.deepsea:deephitomi:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

For me a time in the afternoon        orz...

add deephitomi Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
<artifactId>deephitomi</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>deephitomi-client</module>
    <module>deephitomi-server</module>
    <module>deephitomi-common</module>
    <module>deephitomi-core</module>
    <module>deephitomi-web</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>studio.deepsea</groupId>
            <artifactId>deephitomi-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version></dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a project structured like this:

```
deephitomi
    deephitomi-common
    deephitomi-client
    ...
```

It seems you were running `mvn test` inside `deephitomi-client`.
When you do that,
Maven tries to find its dependency `deephitomi-common` in a repository.
It doesn't know that `deephitomi-common` is in a sibling directory,
it only looks at Maven repositories.

To be able to run `mvn test` inside `deephitomi-client`,
you can install `deephitomi-common` in your local Maven repository.
Run this inside `deephitomi`, the project root directory:

```
mvn install
```

After this, you will be able to run `mvn test` inside `deephitomi-client`:

```
cd deephitomi-client
mvn test
```

Note that if you make any changes to `deephitomi-common` that you want to use by `deephitomi-client`, then you need to repeat the `mvn install` step.

Comment: Thanks so much！old driver ! 666 !